# How to get a single column of emails from a html textarea into array

Tags: arrays, perl

I was thinking I could do this on my own but I need some help.

I need to paste a list of email addresses from a local bands mail list into a textarea and process them my Perl script.

The emails are all in a single column; delimited by newlines:

```
email1@email.com
email2@email.com
email3@email.com
email4@email.com
email5@email.com
```

I would like to obviously get rid of any whitespace:

```
$emailgoodintheory =~ s/\s//ig;
```

and I am running them through basic validation:

```
if (Email::Valid->address($emailgoodintheory)) { #yada
```

I have tried all kinds of ways to get the list into an array.

```
my $toarray = CGI::param('toarray');
my @toarraya = split /\r?\n/, $toarray;
foreach my $address(@toarraya) {
    print qq~ $address[$arrcnt]<br /> ~:
    $arrcnt++;
}
```

Above is just to test to see if I was successful. I have no need to print them. 
It just loops through, grabs the schedules .txt file and sends each member the band schedule. All that other stuff works but I cannot get the textarea into an array!

So, as you can see, I am pretty lost.

Thank you sir(s), may I have another quick lesson?

Comment: Sorry, I do realize my $var names are all over the place but, I think everyone knows what I am typing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem a bit new to Perl, so I will give you a thorough explanation why your code is bad and how you can improve it:

#### 1 Naming conventions:

I see that this seems to be symbolic code, but `$emailgoodintheory` is far less readable than `$emailGoodInTheory` or `$email_good_in_theory`. Pick any scheme and stick to it, just don't write all lowercase.

I suppose that `$emailgoodintheory` holds a single email address. Then applying the regex `s/\s//g` or the transliteration `tr/\s//` will be enough; space characters are not case sensitive.

Using a module to validate adresses is a very good idea. :-)

#### 2 Perl Data Types

Perl has three man types of variables:

*Scalars* can hold strings, numbers or references. They are denoted by the `$` sigil.

*Arrays* can hold an ordered sequence of Scalars. They are denoted by the `@` sigil.

*Hashes* can hold an unordered set of Scalars. Some people tend to know them as dicitonaries. All keys and all values must be Scalars. Hashes are denoted by the `%` sigil.

A word on *context*: When getting a value/element from a hash/array, you have to change the sigil to the data type you want. Usually, we only recover one value (which always is a scalar), so you write `$array[$i]` or `$hash{$key}`. This does not follow any references so

```
 my $arrayref = [1, 2, 3];
 my @array = ($arrayref);
 print @array[0];
```

will not print `123`, but `ARRAY(0xABCDEF)` and give you a warning.

#### 3 Loops in Perl:

Your loop syntax is very weird! You can use C-style loops:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @array; $i++)
```

where `@array` gives the length of the array, because we have a *scalar context*. You could also give `$i` the range of all possible indices in your array:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#array)
```

where `..` is the range operator (in *list context*) and `$#array` gives the highest available index of our array. We can also use a *foreach*-loop:

```
foreach my $element (@array)
```

Note that in Perl, the keywords `for` and `foreach` are interchangeable.

#### 4 What your loop does:

```
foreach my $address(@toarraya) {
   print qq~ $address[$arrcnt]<br /> ~:
   $arrcnt++;
}
```

Here you put each element of `@toarraya` into the scalar `$address`. Then you try to use it as an array (wrong!) and get the index `$arrcnt` out of it. This does not work; I hope your program `die`d.

You can use every loop type given above (you don't need to count manually), but the standard `foreach` loop will suit you best:

```
foreach my $address (@toarraya){
   print "$address<br/>\n";
}
```

A note on quoting syntax: while `qq~ quoted ~` is absolutely legal, this is the most obfuscated code I have seen today. The standard quote `"` would suffice, and when using `qq`, try to use some sort of parenthesis (`({[<|`) as delimiter.

#### 5 complete code:

I assume you wanted to write this:

```
my @addressList = split /\r?\n/, CGI::param('toarray');

foreach my $address (@addressList) {

   # eliminate white spaces
   $address =~ s/\s//g;

   # Test for validity
   unless (Email::Valid->address($address)) {
      # complain, die, you decide
      # I recommend:
      print "<strong>Invalid address »$address«</strong><br/>";
      next;
   }

   print "$address<br/>\n";
   # send that email
}
```

And never forget to `use strict; use warnings;` and possibly `use utf8`.

Comment: The obfuscated version or: How **not** to write Perl: `for(;;){$_=[split ms\r?\ns,CGI::param('toarray')];$_=$_->[$i++]||last;s;\s;;g;next if!Email::Valid->address($_);print"".$_,q<\<br\/\>>.qq;\n;;}`

Comment: Thank you, thank you and .... thank you. You have explained well and I understand your examples perlfectly. I resorted to trying examples I found elsewhere because I could not figure it out. Should I get stuck again, ;-) .. I will come here first.

Comment: @primehunter326 `chomp` is useless when we have whitespaces inside the address like `foo @ example .com`. *CGI.pm* does not have a built-in function to split the field itself. The correct substitute would look like this: `sub split_field {my ($field) = @_; return split m/\015?\012/, CGI::param($field);}` using the CRLF bytes directly. (`\n` is a bit platform specific)

Comment: Hadn't considered the problem of whitespace within a data field, but it's a web form so anything's possible.  Also I misspoke when I said chomp removed whitespace, it does not, only trailing newlines.  I can no longer edit my original comment so I've deleted it.